# Mac to PC RDP same LAN

Tags: windows, macos, remote-desktop

I can RDP into my work desktop from home (using a Macbook Pro, early-2011) but when I'm on the work network with my Mac, I can't bring up my desktop using RDP (same credentials) - I keep getting an error message telling me to ensure that my RDP is enabled.

Other Windows computers on the LAN are able to log in remotely from within the LAN.

Any help, suggestions?

Comment: What’s the remote host (“PC name”) in your RDP connection? We need some details how exactly the connection from home to work is established and what obstacles (port forwarding) are in the way.

Comment: It's the link to the remote server and then once I'm on the server, I log into my account.

Comment: Well, yes, naturally. Please post a screenshot of both your Mac’s non-working connection settings and working connection settings on Windows. You may censor only your username, otherwise it’ll be useless. If you cannot provide this information, we cannot help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a  lack of needed network info to give you an accurate answer, but I'll take a stab at it based on what was provided.

While at work, are you using the same IP/Shortcut to contact the RDP server (your work desktop) you use while at home? If so, then that's most likely your problem.  You need to ensure you're using the internal IP of the RDP server while on the same network as said RDP server (or the work network's router needs to be configured to allow accessing it from inside by using it's outside address).

Comment: That makes sense, but when I use the shortcut for outside from other internal computers, it seems to work ...

Comment: Ok, like was mentioned, we need more information -- do some troubleshooting, and edit your question to include what you did and what the results were.  Start with pinging the RDP server from the Mac by the IP address your RDP shortcut is trying to use. Confirm your RDP shortcut is in fact using the IP you think it is (and that it's the same as the ones on the other computers).